# Unable to cover code for all lines in class

Tags: code-coverage

I am not able to cover code for few lines in class. Can any one help me how to cover code for few lines which not covered in my

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Rob gave the correct answers, still there is one more way to cover your "Catch" block is that -

- Simply Write your "Catch Block" in one line(Only one line - remove all Enter's/Page breaks in code), just like

  }catch(){ My First Line; My Second Line; }

*** For your "For loop" code coverage

- First make sure your **"lNewContact"** list has some values in it,

Better write following debug just before your for loop to make sure that it has some values in it -

`System.debug('----My contacts --'+lNewContact)`

- Second make sure at least one record of your Test class (which is in list **'lNewContact'** has values, which satisfy following criteria) - 
  Assume you have created **"OBJ_CON"** contact record in Test Class, then

  - "Email" is not null,  (eg. OBJ_CON.Email= test@gmail.com)
  - Your **"mUsrDetl"** should contain your Contact record ID,
    (This should be happning somewhere in your code - **mUserDetl.add(OBJ_CON.id)**)
  - AND Your "contact ID is not equal to Email  (This condition really doesn't make sense, double check if you really want to keep this condition)

Enter at least one record with Email value in it, this record's ID is added in **"mUserDetl"** and your records ID is different than you records Email.

Comment: The first suggestion is bad practice and should *not* be recommended.  By artificially squeezing your `catch` block onto one line, you're a) leaving these lines untested, which defeats the purpose of writing tests, and b) making the `catch` block illegible, so when somebody else needs to fix a problem with your code, they can't.  If you're too lazy to write code to cover the `catch` block, just leave those lines without coverage.

Comment: @Rob - Totally Agree with you (as I said earlier). We should write such code in testclass which will somehow fire some exception in TRY block and get entered into the CATCH,   .... "BUT" by seeing at his points, we understood he is new to salesforce and want to get thing done (So I gave him shortcut) -

Answer (score 1):

For the  `} catch(Exception e) { ... }` block, you need to set up your test data such that the code in your `try {}` block throws an exception.

For the `for(Contact con : lNewContact){` block, you need to set up your test data such that the condition `(con.Email != null && mUsrDetl.containsKey(con.Id) && (mUsrDetl.get(con.Id) != con.Email))` evaluates to `true`.